# Send email from Google Sheet 2 weeks prior a date

Tags: email, google-sheets, reminders

I am new to appscript, I would like to send a email to myself as reminder 2 weeks prior the employee next review. Please see below for the Sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SHglnLMT7enbuubed06uUL8Iy7WGjsEasPZuTT74p8I/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to receive a email 2 weeks prior the employee next review (Column F). I would like to get a email that says the Employee name (Column A) has a review coming up.

Thank you!

I have tried to look a few post, but i couldnt find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var ss = sheet.getActiveSheet(); 

  var range = ss.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 6).getValues(); 
  var currdate = new Date(); 

  range.forEach(x => {

    var datediff = Math.floor(((x[5] - currdate)/3600000)/24)

    if(x[5]!= "" && datediff == 14 ){
      console.log(datediff);
      MailApp.sendEmail("ENTER EMAIL HERE","Review reminder for " + x[0], x[0] + " has a review coming up");
    }
  })

}
```

What this script does is on the `range` variable, it gets the data from `row 2` `column A` to `column F`, and since it returns a 2 dimensional array of those values.

Using the `forEach()` method, the names are located on index `x[0]` and the next review date is on the `x[5]` index and then the condition `x[5]!= "" && datediff == 14` evaluates that `x[5]` should not be blank, also the variable `datediff` does the computation for the review date minus the current date to comply with the condition set for the `if condition`.

**SAMPLE TABLE:**
[image]

NOTE: I changed `F5` and `F6` just to test if it works.

**EMAIL OUTPUT:**

[image]

Lastly, add it as a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) so that the script will automatically run depending on the time period you set.

Comment: @adavoodi no problem! I added a small helpful tip below to make it more convenient for you.